How to update changes in model to the database in MVC?
So this is my first time working with MVC. Is there any ways to update the database after the initial migration from the model to the database? Its code first based approach so im not sure if there is an alternative way to do things.
I've been updating the database and models manually as i have some changes in my table and i don't think its an efficient way to do things

Have you seen this?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/

@DanielManta It helped me out thanks~
